# Chatam Sofer on tchiyat hametim

Tags: sources-mekorot, heresy, resurrection-of-the-dead, responsa, chatam-sofer

I heard in [this lecture](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ct8NddDyoFA) that the Chatam Sofer was once told about a certain person in a community who proclaimed publicly that he didn't believe in tchiyat hametim, and that the Chatam Sofer wrote a tshuvah on this, and concluded that tchiyat hametim was not such a central factor in Jewish faith, so the man wasn't really a heretic.

Does anyone know where that tshuvah is?

Comment: This seems extremely unlikely to me.